# Bigcommerce - API Authentication OAUTH2 - Callback URL

Tags: url, callback, bigcommerce

I am developing a Bigcommerce app.

I am at the first stage (authentication)

Bigcommerce requires that the 'call back url' is on an https:// server

My question is:

Can I self-sign the ssl certificate for the callback url server?

Comment: The answer is yes, for anyone who cares.

Comment: Hi, are you able to get context part in callback request? i am using callback url in http:// mode, wouldn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a self-signed cert will work. Their new API requires SSL for all calls, along with the proper headers when performing a POST.